# Get an image from resources of project

Tags: c#

I have `RadioButton` which has a background. Now I need to change background on `MouseEnter` event. I can do that with

```
private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("D:/img/sample.png");
}
```

But I already have that image as resource in project and I don't know how to get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as follow:-

```
private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button.BackgroundImage = <YourNameSpace>.Properties.Resources.<ResourceName>;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use winforms, include the images to your resource:

```
public Form1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
           button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
      }

      void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
      }


      void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
      }
```

Comment: Sorry but its too complicated for me by now =)